# Why wont my sign up form create a new user with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a small project and learning how to use Firebase. I made a simple html form here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>EduVerse - Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign-up.css">
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form_container">
            <div class="title_container">
                <p class="title">Create a new Account</p>
                <span class="subtitle">Already have an account? &nbsp;<a href="sign-in.html">Sign In</a></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="bottom-sect">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="input_container">
                        <label class="input_label" for="user_field">User Name</label>
                        <input placeholder="Name1234" name="input-name" type="text" class="input_field" id="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_container">
                        <label class="input_label" for="email_field">Email</label>
                        <input placeholder="name@mail.com" name="input-name" type="text" class="input_field" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_container">
                        <label class="input_label" for="password_field">Password</label>
                        <input placeholder="Password" name="input-name" type="password" class="input_field" id="password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="sign-up_btn" id="signUp">
                        <span>Sign Up</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="separator">
                    <span>Or</span>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <button type="submit" class="sign-up_ggl">
                        <span>Sign Up with Google</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="sign-up_apl">
                        <span>Sign Up with Apple</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="note">Terms of use &amp; Conditions</p>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type="module" src="js/sign-up.js"></script>
</html>
```

I'm trying to set up authentication and when I click the sign up button it doesn't even produce the alert for an error message on the screen. This is my java script code:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.g    static.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-database.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-auth.js";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDqWEjfCm8D-bvD-Zt_UhBZzScgzGaL-v0",
    authDomain: "eduverse-7d36a.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "eduverse-7d36a",
    storageBucket: "eduverse-7d36a.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "706418380914",
    appId: "1:706418380914:web:ab8091755c0204c4e272eb",
    measurementId: "G-V57JJGKFR8"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const auth = getAuth();
signUp.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        alert("userInitialized");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        alert(errorMessage);
    });
})
```

If anyone has any suggestions id very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most probably comes from the fact that your form is submitted before the Firebase `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method is triggered.

Instead of using the `submit` type for your buttons, use the `button` type which will not submit the form:

```
<button type="button" class="sign-up_btn" id="signUp">
  <span>Sign Up</span>
</button>
```

See the [W3 specification on button types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for more details.

Comment: Hello @NATHANTOLLEY, did you have the time to look at my answer?